# Dynamic GroupName for radiobuttons in WPF (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Right now, I have a DataGrid containing, along with other columns, 5 columns that contains a `<RadioButton>`

Each line has a GroupName that is the "id" in the table of the line, so I know it's unique.

But I'd like to add some lines to that DataGrid, but obviously, there isn't a generated groupname that I could use so I can select all of my radiobuttons in the new row at the same time

Is there a way to do it? Keep in mind that this is a MVVM approach

Here is a visual representation of the issue (The radiobuttons have a style that makes them invisible if unselected and an "X" if selected)
[image: Visual representation of the issue]

Comment: Just use code behind, i.e. `EventHandler` for `Click` event of the `RadioButton` and handle the selection there. This will not break the MvvM pattern. HTH

Comment: This does breaks the MVVM pattern cause events are generated by the GUI, so this makes it untestable. Also in that said event, how can I set the groupname of the radiobutton, I'll have to reference it, this violates the MVVM design twice

Comment: Could you elaborate how this violates MvvM?

Comment: The event is generated by a graphical object, so this makes your ViewModel unstestable without the graphical object (You can't automatize tests since you'll need the GUI) one of the goal of MVVM is to never reference graphical objects in this purpose

Comment: That's UI part to generate an in memory new Item. Your ViewModel should have a create new item command to handle adding new items to a collection. Would you say that this is a MvvM way? Your tests then could handle new item.

Comment: Yes that could be a solution, but I came accross with another solution though, I'll keep this one in mind for another use case where I need explicit groupnames ! thank you

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use a GUID that is generated in the constructor of my object and use this property to name the GroupName property

```
public string GUID { get; set; }

public myObject()
{
    GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}


<RadioButton GroupName="{Binding GUID}" />
```